# Use angular rate it with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use `ng-repeat` with `ng-rate-it` directive.

I would like to store stars values for each caracteristics into a model.caracname but it doesn't work.
You can find the directive here: https://github.com/akempes/angular-rateit

**HTML:**

```js
<div ng-repeat="avis in allavispossible">
    <span class="namecaracforvoteaddproduct">{{avis.name}} :</span><ng-rate-it ng-model="model.{{avis.caracname}}" ng-click="getvaluesf()" max="5" step="1" star-width="20" star-height="20" class="bigstar" read-only="false" resetable="false"></ng-rate-it>
</div>
```

**the scope getvaluesf() function:**

```js
$scope.getvaluesf = function() {
    console.log($scope.model)
}
```

**The error is about {{avis.caracname}} on the ng-model:**

```js
angular.js:14525 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20not%20a%20valid%20identifier&p2=7&p3=model.%7B%7Bavis.caracname%7D%7D&p4=%7B%7Bavis.caracname%7D%7D
    at angular.js:38
```

Comment: how do you want the values in model ? can you share structure of model ? I mean the way you want to store/model the values in `model.something`

Comment: the problem is in `ng-model="model.{{avis.caracname}}"` you can use something in this way in ng-model. It is not parsable

Comment: @UsmanRana so yes what should I do??

Comment: @UsmanRana the model grow for each new value. This is how the directive work. like if you repeat 3var and you click on var1 and var2 the model look like model = ["var1" : "valuestar1", "var2" : ""valuestar2"] and if the model object will update to var1 var 2 and add var 3 to the object.

Comment: @UsmanRana I did it worked with scope ng-show, I added in the html all possible caracs but the code will scared. so I prefer to use ng repeat and store data in mysql but it doestn't work in this way I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not using "double curly markup" with [`ngModel` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). Simply use `avis.caracname` for it:

```
<ng-rate-it ng-model="avis.caracname" max="5" step="1" star-width="20" star-height="20" class="bigstar" read-only="false" resetable="false"></ng-rate-it>
```

Instead of using [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) on `ng-rate-it` element, you should better use callbacks provided in the documentation (probably `rated` callback).

Comment: How to get the value??

Comment: The value is stored in `avis.caracname`. So check the `allavispossible` array and look for it at the specified index. Change your `getvaluesf` method to be like `$scope.getvaluesf = function(avis) {
    console.log(avis.caracname)
}` and markup to be `ng-click="getvaluesf(avis)"`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed, ng-click="getvaluesf(allavispossible)" ng-model="avis.score" ( cause mode="avis.caracname" erased value that I needed) to create a new score element in my objects And now I have all values in a single array ! Thanks.

Comment: Now I can check if my array contain all score element with a non empty value and send it to the server. Thanks

Comment: Glad it was helpful :)